# Finding the maxima of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^3+z^2+z+1}$ and the integral $\int_Cf(z)\mathrm dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, maxima-minima

Could you please explain to me how to find the maxima of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^3+z^2+z+1}$ and the integral $\int_Cf(z)\mathrm dz$, where $C$ is an anticlockwise circle of radius $2$ centred around $(0,0)$?

For the maxima, I made the assumption they would be at the same points as for $z^3+z^2+z+1$ so I calculated $3z^2+2z+1=0$ giving $z=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt8}{6}$ and substituted both z into the original $f(z)$, is this correct, and is there a simpler way?

For the integral, I calculated $z^3+z^2+z+1=(z+1)(z+i)(z-i)$ but am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: You must give us $C$, because the integral depends on it.

Comment: Sorry, C is an anticlockwise circle of radius 2 centred around (0,0).

Comment: Use partial-fraction decomposition and cauchy's integral formula

Comment: What exactly do you mean by maxima, maxima of $|f|$? You can't achieve it since $f$ has poles. And if you calculate maxima of $|z^3+z^2+z+1|$ you most definitely won't get maxima of $|f|$ since $x\mapsto 1/x$ is decreasing on $(0,+\infty)$. Or you want to know _local_ extrema?

Comment: Local maxima. So the points at which z stops going downwards and starts going upwards, or vice versa. This should be when $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$, right?

Comment: $f(z)=o\left(\frac{1}{|z|}\right)$ as $|z|\to +\infty$, hence if $C$ is a contour enclosing $-1,\pm i$ we have that $\oint_{C} f(z)\,dz = 0$ by the residue theorem.

Answer (score 0):

We have a partial-fraction decomposition
\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac{1}{2(z+1)}+\frac{1-z}{2(z^2+1)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2(z+1)}+\frac{i(1-z)}{4(z+i)}-\frac{i(1-z)}{4(z-i)}
\end{align}
We then obtain by cauchy's integral formula
\begin{align}
\oint_C f(z)dz=2\pi i\Big(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i(1+i)}{4}-\frac{i(1-i)}{4}\Big)=0
\end{align}